# Babylonian square root iterations

Tags: python, loops, math

Background: The Babylonians used an iterative method to calculate square roots by hand as early as 1500 BC. Here are the steps to find the square root of a positive number n:

Start with an initial guess for the square root. This guess can be anything other than 0.
Get a new guess using the following formula: newGuess = (guess + n / guess) / 2.
Repeat step 2, now with the newGuess as the guess.
Continue repeating until the difference between newGuess and guess is smaller than a value we'll call epsilon.
The newGuess at the end of this process is an approximation of the square root.
With this in mind, write the function babylonianSqureRootIterations(n, initialGuess, epsilon) which takes a positive int n, a positive float representing the initial guess, and a positive float epsilon. Return the number of times the above formula needs to be repeated to converge on a square root.

Why is this code not returning the right results?

```
def babylonianSquareRootIterations(n, initialGuess, epsilon):
    itr = 0
    while initialGuess > 0:
        newGuess = ((initialGuess + n / initialGuess) / 2.0)
        initialGuess = newGuess
        difference = initialGuess**2 - n
        if abs(difference) <= epsilon:
            itr += 1
            break
        itr += 1
    return itr
```

## These return 3 but they should return 4.

```
print(babylonianSquareRootIterations(4, 7, 0.25))
print(babylonianSquareRootIterations(0.49, 2, 0.05))
print(babylonianSquareRootIterations(25, 10, .05))
```

Comment: What arguments are you giving, what result are you expecting, what are you getting instead?

Comment: `(initialGuess + n / initialGuess)` should be `(initialGuess + n) / initialGuess`

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/square-root-of-a-perfect-square/

Comment: @Barmar That's not correct.  Consider the goal, when the guess *is* the square root of n.  In that case, the expression should evaluate to the guess itself.  Your addition of incorrect parentheses breaks that, rather horribly.  E.g. `(sqrt(2) + 2/sqrt(2)) / 2 = sqrt(2)`.  But `((sqrt(2) + 2) / sqrt(2)) / 2` isn't even close.

Comment: @kian Are you sure it's giving the wrong answer?  Give an example of the three parameters, along with the result you expect and the result you get.

Comment: @Barmar By the way, this is also known as Newton's method, and it's correct in the post.

Comment: The code seems to be working fine to me. I tested babylonianSquareRootIterations(100, 5, 0.02), and it seems to work fine. It returns a result of 4, and is correct up to 6 significant digits. If there is some case where you think it's not working you should add that to your question.

Comment: Problem statement says "Continue repeating until the difference between newGuess and guess is smaller than a value we'll call epsilon" so you need to look at `difference = newGuess - guess`, not `difference = guess**2 - n` which is what you have.

Answer (score -1):

the code is actually returning the number of iterations.

presumably you want to return the square root. If so, you just need to change the return:

```py
def babylonianSquareRootIterations(n, initialGuess, epsilon):
    itr = 0
    while initialGuess > 0:
        newGuess = ((initialGuess + n / initialGuess) / 2.0)
        initialGuess = newGuess
        difference = initialGuess**2 - n
        if abs(difference) <= epsilon:
            itr += 1
            break
        itr += 1
    return initialGuess, itr   # <-- changed this

# test the function
square_root, iterations = babylonianSquareRootIterations(100, 50, 0.01)
print('square root:', square_root)
print('number of iterations:', iterations)
```

the result:

```
square root: 10.000046356507898
number of iterations: 5
```

Also, it is possible to see the value at each step so in the statement from the OP by adding a `print` statement: `babylonianSquareRootIterations(4, 7, 0.25)` *should return 4*, appears to be incorrect as these are the 3 iterations with this method as seen here:

```
1 3.7857142857142856
2 2.4211590296495955
3 2.0366301688743387
(2.0366301688743387, 3)
```

Comment: I agree it's unusual to return the number of iterations instead of the square root, but the problem statement explicitly says, "Return the number of times the above formula needs to be repeated to converge on a square root."

Comment: "the code is actually returning the number of iterations. presumably you want to return the square root." suggests the problem statement wasn't read carefully. The code posted is solving a different problem than what's in the problem statement. As OP was saying, the number of iterations is different than what they were told is the correct result; that's not changed by returning the approximate root in addition to the number of iterations.

Comment: @RobertDodier.  Agreed.  But it apears that the OP has been told **the wrong answer** and accepted this as given...  the number of iterations is clearly 3 when using this method !!  Can you show that the asnwer is anything but 3 ?

Comment: The termination criterion as stated is "Continue repeating until the difference between newGuess and guess is smaller than a value we'll call epsilon", which is not the test implemented by OP (same as in the code you posted).